# InDesign: How to outline fonts when exporting to pdf

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

Is there a way to outline fonts when exporting to pdf? I know if a hacky way, but I am wondering if anyone knows the correct way to do it in the most recent version of InDesign (cc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@zachzurn... I actually came across this write up and it might be exactly what you are looking for.

https://indesignsecrets.com/outlining-fonts-the-2016-edition.php

Comment: @zachzurn Yeah, unfortunately.  I would think implementing that feature a few others on PDF export from ID would be a no brainer for Adobe.